# invariant measures for the independently coupled Feller process

Tags: functional-analysis, probability-theory

If I take countably many Markov processes and couple them independently, how does the collection of invariant measures for the coupled process relate to those of the marginals?  I conjecture that it is the closed convex hull in weak topology of the products of marginal invariant measures.  How do I see this?  My progress so far is to verify that this works for a countable coupling of $\{0,1\}$-valued markov chains.  (For concreteness, you can assume I mean continuous time Feller processes, although all the other variations of what I could mean should behave similarly.)